# jQuery: Toggle class on jQuery element that has been added to the DOM via .wrap()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm having problems manipulating an element's class attribute because I've added it to the DOM using .wrap(). It simply wont change the attribute at all, even though everything seems to be in order.

If I use something else than .wrap() or .wrapInner() everything works as expected. If I change .toggleClass() to an if/else if still wont work.

One could of course work around it but I'd rather find the root of the problem and learn something along the way.

Here's the code in question:

```
$('.tour-category').each(function () {
    var tour_list = $(this);
    var header = tour_list.parent().find('h4');
    var link = $('<a>', {
        href: '#',
        'class': 'tour-category-toggler',
        click: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            tour_list.slideToggle(200);
            link.toggleClass('close');
        }
    });

    tour_list.hide();
    header.wrap(link);
});
```

Maybe there's something I'm missing, or is this perhaps a bug in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
link.toggleClass('close');
```

into

```
$(this).toggleClass('close');
```

Comment: Oh my, that was quick – and worked like a charm. May I ask why this makes a difference?

Comment: JavaScript scope. `link` is a bit tricky to find and if something is found, it is probably not the correct element. But `$(this)` for sure refers to the actual element.

Comment: With your code you're referencing a variable (always the same variable for all links) inside a loop and at the end of that loop the reference may be incorrect, while my suggestion use an explicit reference to the element itself